# Suggestion regarding transition to Mathematics

Tags: book-recommendation, advice

I have studied mathematics upto High school level and also studied Calculus 1 and 2. I also have studied basic ODE. Recently i read a book "The Heart of Mathematics : Invitation to effective thinking". Now i feel like pursuing mathematics especially number theory area on my own. I would welcome suggestions of experienced mathematicians so as to what should be the pathway to it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm glad you liked "Heart of Mathematics", it's one of my favorite books.

You might try a book like "Elementary Number Theory and Its Applications" by Rosen.  Hardy and Wright, recommended in another reply, is an excellent book, but it's a big jump from "Heart of Mathematics" to Hardy and Wright.  Rosen's book is simpler, and the only prerequisite is high-school algebra.

Answer (score 2):

You could start by working your way through one or two of the classic texts on number theory such as

*An Introduction To The Theory Of Numbers* by G.H. Hardy and E.M. Wright

*Number Theory* by George E. Andrews

*The Higher Arithmetic: An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers* by H. Davenport

*An Adventurer's Guide to Number Theory* by Richard Friedberg

As with all mathematics textbooks, it is important to work through the problems at the end of each chapter to confirm and consolidate your understanding.

Also worth a mention is *A Pathway into Number Theory* by R.P. Burn, which consists of a series of problems which lead you to discover the basic results of number theory for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Some poeple told me to study Analysis, Algebra and Topology before studying number theory. Is that true?

Comment: Not really. Basic number theory can be studied on its own, as long as you have some idea of how a formal mathematical proof works. More advanced number theory requires a knowledge of analysis, group theory (which is part of algebra) and maybe topology too, but you can get a long way before you need to use those tools.

Comment: from where can i download pathway into number theory book?